# Copy-Item slowness - 40mins to filter and copy 5500 files?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I recently wrote a tiny little script to help me pull subfolders containing lots of little txt files out of a larger directory containing many different subfolders and files.

All in all I copied ~17GB worth of folders (~100 folders containing ~5,500 files) containing txt files from an external hdd to my local drive. The connection was USB 2.0.

It took ~40 minutes to do this! Why did this take so long?

Was the overhead more to do with my code, or the slowness of an outdated data connection? What shortcuts can I take in the future? Is robocopy inherently faster than copy-item? If so, why?

```
$mainDir = Get-ChildItem 'E:\Some Big Directory\' -Recurse | Where {$_.Mode -match 'd'} | % {$_.FullName}

ForEach($dir in $mainDir){
    if($dir.ToString() -match 'SubfoldersIWant'){
        Copy-Item -Path $($dir + '\TheActualFolderIWant\*') -Destination 'C:\somwhere' -Recurse
    }
}
```

The folder structure is somewhat as follows (sized WAY down):

```
Some Big Directory
    -SubfoldersIWant1
    -subFolderIDontwant
        -random.txt
    -subFoldersIWant
        -*.txt
    -rando.jpg
    -I dont want this folder
    -random junk
    -SubfoldersIWant2
    -subFolderIDontwant
        -random.txt
    -subFoldersIWant
        -*.txt
    -rando.jpg
    -dontwantthiseither.jpg
```

Comment: I'd replace `% {$_.fullname}` in first line with `select -expand fullname`.

Comment: USB2 is ten-times slower than USB3 so you might want to think about upgrading your drive if you're planning on doing this often.

Comment: @JamesC. Funny enough the drive is 3.0, but my current workstation is an old dell with only 2.0 :(

Comment: A USB3 card is a cheap way to add USB3 ports if you want to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this one line:

```
Get-ChildItem 'E:\Some Big Directory' -Directory -Recurse | Where {$_.FullName -match 'SubfoldersIWant'} | Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\somwhere' -Recurse
```

This way, the filtering is much faster. But honestly, it is not likely to have a big effect, since your bottleneck seems to be the data transfer rate.

Comment: You might want to use `-match` instead of `-eq` as OP lists "SubfoldersIWant2" aswell as "SubfoldersIWant"

Comment: I'll give this a try in a moment and let you know if it's any faster! If not I'll accept the answer (bottleneck is usb 2.0)

Comment: @JamesC. `-match` is indeed useful in case he want to filter the path with regex. In this case, you can see in the question the line `Where {$_.Mode -match 'd'}`, So he clearly thought `-mach` just means equal. but you are essentially right, so I stand corrected :)